# How to ask permission from the user to grant access to its information using FB API

Tags: javascript, facebook-graph-api, facebook-javascript-sdk

I have the code below that allows the user to sign up to our app using the Facebook SDK API. It is working well but I want to ask the user to grant us a permission for their `picture,birthday,address,email,gender,location` and other information.

```
window.fbAsyncInit = () => {
    //SDK loaded, initialize it
    FB.init({
        appId      : 'my-app-id',
        xfbml      : true,
        version    : 'v3.2'
    });

    //check user session and refresh it
    FB.getLoginStatus((response) => {
        if (response.status === 'connected') {
            //user is authorized
            document.getElementById('loginBtn').style.display = 'none';
            document.getElementById('logoutBtn').style.display = 'block';
            connectAPI(response);
        } else {

        }
    });
};

//add event listener to login button
document.getElementById('loginBtn').addEventListener('click', () => {
    //do the login
    FB.login((response) => {
        if (response.authResponse) {
            //user just authorized your app
            document.getElementById('loginBtn').style.display = 'none';

        }
    }, {
        scope: 'email', //===========change
        return_scopes: true,
        auth_type: 'rerequest'
    });
}, false);

document.getElementById('logoutBtn').addEventListener('click', () => {
    FB.logout((response) => {
        if(response.status === 'unknown'){
            document.getElementById('loginBtn').style.display = 'block';
            $('.btn-logout').hide();
        }
    });
}, false);

// Load the SDK asynchronously
(function(d, s, id) {
    var js, fjs = d.getElementsByTagName(s)[0];
    if (d.getElementById(id)) return;
    js = d.createElement(s); js.id = id;
    js.src = "https://connect.facebook.net/en_US/sdk.js";
    fjs.parentNode.insertBefore(js, fjs);
}(document, 'script', 'facebook-jssdk'));

//successful log in
function connectAPI(respo) {
    console.log(respo);
}
```

The output is like this:

[image]

But I am expecting the output to be like this:

[image: photo from google https://www.google.com/url?sa=i&source=images&cd=&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=2ahUKEwjvpcWIj6bgAhXLQN4KHUCLAN0QjRx6BAgBEAU&url=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.studytutorial.in%2Fphp-facebook-login-and-integration-in-php-website-tutorial&psig=AOvVaw1FWjb0gj6NdviN0cqfzhsk&ust=1549508480183839]

I've tried changing this line:

```
scope: 'email'
```

to:

```
scope: 'email,name,picture,birthday,address,email,gender,location',
```

But the display of the pop out window is like this:

[image]

Where should I properly insert my scope parameters?

Comment: Someone has any idea on this, please?

Comment: did you try as a user with a role in the app?

Comment: @luschn Yes. It's what I'm using, and when I have let the other users log in, it will prompt that the app is still at development mode.

Answer (score 0):

There is no permission called "name" or "picture", read this: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/facebook-login/permissions

Also, there is no `address` permission and the `location` permission is actually called `user_location`. Same for `birthday` and `gender`. Try with the correct ones and don´t use `email` twice:

```
scope: 'email,public_profile,user_birthday,user_gender,user_location'
```

Don´t just invent permissions, the API reference tells you exactly which ones exist ;)

Comment: Thanks for this, but it's still the same :(

Comment: in that case, i assume that it´s just a temporary problem on facebook. you can also try adding just ONE permission next to email, to find out if a specific one generates the problem.